# Nginx url rewrite works only for /

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

Porting my angular app to `nginx`.

My url rewrite config works only for the `/` location. If I go to `localhost:5000/login` in the browser, I get a 404 error.

Here's my nginx.conf

```
http {
    include              /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type         application/octet-stream;

    log_format           main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status             $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent"  "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log           /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile             on;
    #tcp_nopush          on;

    keepalive_timeout    65;

    #gzip                on;

    include              /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen              80;
        root                /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
            root               /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index              index.html;

            try_files          $uri $uri/ /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html;
        }


    }
}
```

The logs

```
2020/02/05 06:44:29 [error] 6#6: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /login HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:5000"
172.17.0.1 - - [05/Feb/2020:06:44:29 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was including the default conf file with the following line,

`include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`

This was matching rules before it could hit my `location` block. Removing this line got it working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `try_files` with the app root file.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html;
```

Ref: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a regex on the location block, if not nginx only apply this location to the exact match.

```
location ~* /.* {
            root               /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index              index.html;

            try_files          $uri $uri/ /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
```

You can see some examples and more info [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms)